# Spark Scala : Add new column without looping throw same table many times

Tags: scala, apache-spark, query-optimization

I want to add a new column called **activeIOsAtSite** that has a value of '**Y**' or '**N**'.

the value will be added according to the following condition:

For each column **SITE_SITE_ID** in row of the table bellow; if the **SITE_SITE_ID** has:

`(APPLICATION_SOURCE == 'CIBASE' AND STANDARD_STATUS =='ACTIVE')`

In this case the value should be ***'Y' otherwise 'N'***

IS there a was to do that without **iterate** on the **same table** over and over again (for each row), because the table I have is so **big** and I need to do that in the **fastest** way possible?

Example of desired result:

[image]

I tried to do something like that, but I'm not sure if it is correct:

```
finvInventoryAllDf
  .withColumn(
    "activeIOsAtSite",
    activeIOsAtSiteGenerator(finvInventoryAllDf, col("Site_siteId"))
  )
```

with `activeIOsAtSiteGenerator()` is a function where I verify the conditions above:

```
  def activeIOsAtSiteGenerator(dataFrame: DataFrame, site_siteId: Column): Column = {
    val count = dataFrame
      .where(col("Site_siteId") === site_siteId)
      .where("InstalledOffer_installedOfferId IS NOT NULL AND InstalledOffer_installedOfferId NOT IN ('','null','NULL') AND UPPER(InstalledOffer_standardStatus) IN ('ACTIVE') AND UPPER(InstalledOffer_applicationSource) IN('CIBASE')")
      .count()
    if (count > 0)
      lit("Y")
    else
      lit("N")
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first `groupBy` the unique ID, then `collect_set` to check whether the column contains any of the combo you mentioned.

```
var grouped = df
  .groupBy("SITE_SITE_ID").agg(collect_set(array("APPLICATION_SOURCE", "STANDARD_STATUS")).as("array"))
  .withColumn("indicator",
    expr("transform(array, x -> array_contains(x, 'CIBASE') and array_contains(x, 'ACTIVE'))")
  )
```

In case order matters:

```
.withColumn("indicator",
    expr("transform(array, x -> lower(element_at(x, 1)) = 'cibase' and lower(element_at(x, 2)) = 'active')")
)
```

Current form of what we have:

```
+------------+------------------------------------+-------------+
|SITE_SITE_ID|array                               |indicator    |
+------------+------------------------------------+-------------+
|si_2        |[[SLOW, STASH]]                     |[false]      | <- make this N
|si_3        |[[MEDIUM, TREE]]                    |[false]      | <- make this N
|si_1        |[[FAST, DISABLED], [CIBASE, ACTIVE]]|[false, true]| <- make this Y (pair found)
+------------+------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Then we move on:

```
  grouped = grouped.withColumn("indicator",
    when(array_contains(col("indicator"), true), "Y").otherwise("N")
  )
  .drop("array")
```

```
+------------+---------+
|SITE_SITE_ID|indicator|
+------------+---------+
|si_2        |N        |
|si_3        |N        |
|si_1        |Y        |
+------------+---------+
```

The `collected_set` returns an array of arrays, that is why we check for the combo, and we check again, if there is one true within the array (the combo has been found), return `Y` otherwise `N`; finally, we drop `array` column.

Grouped's sample:

```
+------------+---------+
|SITE_SITE_ID|indicator|
+------------+---------+
|si_2        |N        |
|si_3        |N        |
|si_1        |Y        |
+------------+---------+
```

Finally, we join our main table with `grouped`:

```
df.join(grouped, Seq("SITE_SITE_ID"))
```

Final result:

```
+------------+-----+------------------+---------------+---------+
|SITE_SITE_ID|IR_ID|APPLICATION_SOURCE|STANDARD_STATUS|indicator|
+------------+-----+------------------+---------------+---------+
|si_2        |ir2  |SLOW              |STASH          |N        |
|si_3        |ir3  |MEDIUM            |TREE           |N        |
|si_1        |ir1  |FAST              |DISABLED       |Y        |
|si_1        |ir4  |CIBASE            |ACTIVE         |Y        |
+------------+-----+------------------+---------------+---------+
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hello Vilalabinot, thank you for your responsiveness and help; is there anyway to ignore case sensitivity in array_contains ?

Comment: I understand now the array x, but i want to know how can chose the index of element in the array x  that I will use for comparing; for example if x=[cibase,active], i want to choose x.1 to compare with 'cibase' and the same thing for x.2..is there any sytax for that. I want that because the values could be duplicated in the same array..they are not consistent

Comment: After grouping by and collecting set, our `x = [[FAST, DISABLED], [CIBASE, ACTIVE]]`, so we are saying, if any of the arrays within the big array contains `CIBASE and ACTIVE`, make that `Y`. The order of the columns does not matter in this case, does it? I edited the post for a better output of what we currently are dealing with.

Comment: actually the order does matter; what should be is: if any of the arrays within the big array has `the first element equalsIgnoreCase 'CIBASE' and second element equalsIgnoreCase 'ACTIVE'`  **then**  the indicator should be **true**  **otherwise false**.. because we could find that the first element contains 'ACTIVE' instead of 'CIBASE' and same thing for the second one; in this case it should be false not true, this is why the order matter in the comparing

Comment: I tried to edit your answer and do `UPPER(x[0]) IN ('CIBASE') AND UPPER(x[1]) IN ('ACTIVE')`, but I get a **syntax error**

Comment: Replace the previous `transform` with this:

`expr("transform(array, x -> lower(element_at(x, 1)) = 'cibase' and lower(element_at(x, 2)) = 'active')")`

the should work fine! - edited the answer as well

Comment: thank you for your reply vilabinot, I did as you said but apparently although your answer is correct 100% but the problem I was facing is also related to a syntax error where the `->` in the transform operation is not being recognized by spark. I created a question for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73571440/spark-scala-extraneous-input-parseexception-in-transform

Answer (score 0):

@vilalabinot answer is hundred per cent correct! but I had to improve it using the same logic with an udf function instead:

so we still need to group by SITE_SITE_ID:

```
val grouped0 = finvInventoryAllDf
  .groupBy("SITE_SITE_ID")
  .agg(
    collect_set(
      array(
        "InstalledOffer_applicationSource",
        "InstalledOffer_standardStatus", "InstalledOffer_installedOfferId"
      )
    ).as("array")
  )
```

But to create the new field I use a udf that will directly give me Y or N value according to the desired conditions, so :

```
grouped0
.withColumn("activeIOsAtSite", buildFieldActiveIOsAtSite_UDF(col("array")))
.drop("array")
```

The declaration of UDF I'm using:

```
val buildFieldActiveIOsAtSite_UDF = udf(buildFieldActiveIOsAtSite _)
```

And finally the function of this udf:

```
  def buildFieldActiveIOsAtSite(rows: mutable.WrappedArray[mutable.WrappedArray[String]]): String = {
    var yesOrNoCondition = "N";

    breakable {
      rows.array.foreach(r => {
        val installedOffer_applicationSource = Option(r(0)).getOrElse("")
        val installedOffer_standardStatus = Option(r(1)).getOrElse("")
        val InstalledOffer_installedOfferId = Option(r(2)).getOrElse("")


        val yesCondition = InstalledOffer_installedOfferId.nonEmpty &&
          !InstalledOffer_installedOfferId.equalsIgnoreCase("null") &&
          installedOffer_standardStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("active") &&
          installedOffer_applicationSource.equalsIgnoreCase("CIBASE")
        if (yesCondition) {
          yesOrNoCondition = "Y"
          break
        }
      })

    }
    yesOrNoCondition
  }
```

Now all what remains to do is a small join with the main dataframe:

```
val finvResultOutput1 = finvInventoryAllDf.join(grouped0, Seq("SITE_SITE_ID"))
```